# how to add back button In Quiz App?

Tags: android

***Please Give Me some Solution to add back button in quiz app***

What I want to create is back button in my quiz app, **the questions come from database**. I want button to go to previous question without messing up.I am new to android can any one help me to solve the problem..

```
package in.gtarena.myquizapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import in.gtarena.myquizapp.db.DBAdapter;
import in.gtarena.myquizapp.model.Question;

public class ComputerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private List<Question> questionsList;
   private Question currentQuestion;

    private TextView txtQuestion,tvNoOfQs;
    private RadioButton rbtnA, rbtnB, rbtnC,rbtnD;
    private Button btnNext,btnBack;
    private RadioGroup  grp;
    private int obtainedScore=0;
    private int questionId=0;

    private int answeredQsNo=0;

    ArrayList<String> myAnsList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_concept);
        init();
        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

        //Initialize the database
        final DBAdapter dbAdapter =new DBAdapter(this);
        questionsList= dbAdapter.getQuestions();
        currentQuestion =questionsList.get(questionId);

        //Set question
        setQuestionsView();

        //Check and Next
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

                Log.e("Answer ID", "Selected Positioned  value - "+grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

                if(answer!=null){
                    Log.e("Answer", currentQuestion.getANSWER() + " -- " + answer.getText());
                    //Add answer to the list
                    myAnsList.add(""+answer.getText());

                    if(currentQuestion.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText())){
                        obtainedScore++;
                        Log.e("comments", "Correct Answer");
                        Log.d("score", "Obtained score " + obtainedScore);
                    }else{
                        Log.e("comments", "Wrong Answer");
                    }
                    if(questionId < dbAdapter.rowCount()){
                        currentQuestion =questionsList.get(questionId);
                        setQuestionsView();
                    }else{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ComputerActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);

                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putInt("score", obtainedScore);
                        b.putInt("totalQs", questionsList.size());
                        b.putStringArrayList("myAnsList", myAnsList);
                        intent.putExtras(b);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.e("comments", "No Answer");
                }
                //Need to clear the checked item id
                grp.clearCheck();

            }//end onClick Method
        });

        //Check and Back
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE FOR GO BACK TO PREVIOUS QUESTION//
            }
        });

    }

    public void init(){
        tvNoOfQs=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvNumberOfQuestions);
        txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
        rbtnA=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        rbtnB=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        rbtnC=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
        rbtnD=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio3);

        btnNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

        myAnsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }


    private void setQuestionsView()
    {
        rbtnA.setChecked(false);
        rbtnB.setChecked(false);
        rbtnC.setChecked(false);
        rbtnD.setChecked(false);

        answeredQsNo=questionId+1;
        tvNoOfQs.setText("Questions "+answeredQsNo+" of "+questionsList.size());

        txtQuestion.setText(currentQuestion.getQUESTION());
        rbtnA.setText(currentQuestion.getOptionA());
        rbtnB.setText(currentQuestion.getOptionB());
        rbtnC.setText(currentQuestion.getOptionC());
        rbtnD.setText(currentQuestion.getOptionD());

        questionId++;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't go through entire code, what are you using fragments to show questions or viewpagers?

Comment: fragment is used in my code

Comment: Welcome to StackoverFlow.  You may want to consider reading the page named:  [ask]   and then use the information  on it to make a few useful changes to your question.  There is lots of useful information in that guide and is worth taking a few minutes to read entirely.  Guide:  ->  [ask]  <-

Answer (score 0):

Are you using separate activity for every question?
If yes, then you can use onBackPressed method.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy for you to go back to question if you provide a id(ex.1,2,3..) for every question in database and take a variable named id and increment id every time you click the next button and fetch the question matching to the id and when you press back button the decrement id and fetch the question again...

Just decrement questionid in back button listener and call the questions again

Comment: this code does not work for me //Check and Back
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 if(questionId>0) {
                    questionId--; // here you decrement
                    currentQuestion=questionsList.get(questionId);  // here you load
                    setQuestionsView();
                    grp.clearCheck();
                } else {
                    btnBack.setEnabled(false);
                } 
            }
        });

Comment: What is happening exactly can you elaborate

Comment: You need not do all this stuff simply decrement value of question id and call setQuestionsView() in back button pressed

Comment: **not working**                                              btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                questionId--;
                currentQuestion=questionsList.get(questionId);
                setQuestionsView();
            }
        });

Comment: Let me know exactly whats happening your not going back or question is not displayed

Comment: if you want to check whole code can i send you source code

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by two approaches :

- Create a button and than link that button to the previous activity
- Create a method onBackPressed like this code :

  ```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(OrderList.this, MainActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  }
  ```

You can simply use the second code in any activity to lead you back to previous activity.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: i have only one activity for all questions

Comment: yeah you can paste the above code after the onOptionItemSelected method